# When is the use of "|| true" needed in bash?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, travis-ci

I use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/) to do unit testing for my open source project.  While configuring my `.travis.yml` file I've seen examples on several other projects, and some inconsistent use of `|| true` following some conditionals in the script.  I have seen them in two formats.

When the statement is executed as a conditional, I understand the need for `|| true` to ensure the command returns "success" and allows the script to continue.  A non-match on the name would be false, omit execution of later commands after `&&`, but eventually return successful after `|| true`.

```
- '[ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "osx" ] && brew install ant || true'
```

However, I have also seen the conditional applied after `if ... fi` conditionals, such as this example:

```
- if [ "${TRAVIS_CPU_ARCH}" == "arm64" ]; then 
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk libltdl-dev;
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64;
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH; 
  fi || true
```

My own testing indicates it makes no difference whether that's included or not.  For example, this conditional does not stop the test, even when it evaluates to false.  For example:

```
if [ "${TRAVIS_BRANCH}" == "coverity_scan" ]; then exit 0; fi
```

Travis produces this output, showing a "true" result:

> The command "if [ "${TRAVIS_BRANCH}" == "coverity_scan" ]; then exit 0; fi" exited with 0.

The script continues past this point without complaint, on the "master" branch.  My assessment is that an `if [ false ] then; ...; fi` conditional either returns true, or is effectively a no-operation, and it's not needed.

Is `|| true` necessary, or even useful, to add after a `if ... fi` conditional in the case where the conditional is false?  (Assume I want the script to fail if the conditional is true and a statement inside it fails.)

Comment: `|| true` ensures that even if the command fails, the script will continue. Did your testing make any part of the `if` fail?

Comment: There are multiple branches. Only one of them has that "arm64" conditional true, but none of the others fail; it just bypasses the `if ... fi`

Comment: `|| true` is effectively the same as `( if [ ... ] then ...; else exit 0; fi )`.  I'm not familiar with Travis but I bet that it complains if any of its scripted commands returns with a non-zero exit code; `|| true` would bypass that behavior.

Comment: As Mad physicist explains, `|| true` ensures that the script continues gracefully. You could refer to this questions answer to see a more deeper explanation: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325714](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325714)

Comment: Thanks... I'd found similar answers, the question is whether `if [ false ] then ;... ; fi` returns true.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear precisely what I understand already and what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When is the use of “|| true” needed in bash?

When the script is executed in an environment when it's execution will stop if any of the expressions will return with nonzero exit status. Such examples are with `set -e` or like your example inside ci/cd tools.

The chain:

```
false && true
#  $? is 1
```

will exit with nonzero exit status. I find people use `|| true` or shorter `||:` in such scripts to make the commands lists with `&&` exit with zero status even if it one of the commands fail. Typically:

```
 [ -e "env_file" ] && . "env_file" ||:
```

> I have also seen the conditional applied after if ... fi conditionals

This certain usage you showed seems to be some left-over or inserted by some over-protective programmer. `export` always returns with a zero exit status.

If the expression in `if` will exit with zero exit status then the `if` body will execute. The exit status of `if` command is the exit status of last command executed (as usuall in groups).

```
if true; then
   dont care;
   dont care;
   false
fi 
#  exits with exit status of false
```

Thus programmer can insert `|| true` to make the exit status of `if` expression to zero.

> My assessment is that an if [ false ] then; ...; fi

`[ false ]` returns with zero exit status, because the string `false` has nonzero length. I think you meant to execute the command `false` with `if false`.

> Is || true necessary, or even useful, to add after a if ... fi conditional in the case where the conditional is false?

If there are no `ifelse` block or `else` block that get executed like in the code presented, then no, `if` will return with success. I think a qoute from manual would be best [bash manual Conditional Constructs if](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-commands_002c-conditional):

> if
>
> ... The return status [of `if`] is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.

Comment: Thank you! The statement "If there are no ifelse block or else block that get executed like in the code presented, then no, if will return with success" is exactly what I needed (along with the bash manual documentation of 0 return), and thanks for the reference.  For clarity, the `if [false]` was my shorthand for `if [ <some condition that evaluates false> ]` but the non-empty comment is helpful.